# Filter function not retruning anything in react native

Tags: react-native, filter

comment.dishID === dishID )} />

"list" in the above case is not showing any values although "comments" has an array also "dishID" is getting set propely. Now "comment.dishID" has values corresponding to value in "dishID"

Not sure why filter function is not working properly

Comment: Please add proper detailed code.

Comment: please make sure `comment.dishID` and `dishID` has the same data type

Comment: Do not forget to return true when your condition is satisfied

Comment: @randomkrishna i think the data type would be same since I have numeric values in both and I have not specified any data type hence it should take datat type by default

Comment: <ScrollView>
                <RenderDish dish={this.state.dishes[+dishID]} />
                <RenderComments list={this.state.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishID === dishID )} />
            </ScrollView>

Comment: @NimeshBhalani what does that mean and how should I do it

Comment: Basically, filter function returns data based on your predictor so you can use your predictor as

`const finalArray = array.filter((data,index) => {
    if(data.id === id) return true;
})` 
Like this

Comment: thanks everyone it is done now, there was a problem in Varaible name